# Distance and slope of two points with single functions

Tags: c++, function, formula

I have this assignment that asks to use functions in order to calculate the distance and slope of two points. The thing is I don't really understand how I can use a single function for two separate variables(has to be done this way for the assignment). In this case, the formula asks for x1 and x2, but I have to use a single function. So my question is how can I use my getX and getY functions that prompts for x and y twice? Basically use a single function for both first and second values. Hope that makes more sense.

```
/*Include statements*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Given Prototypes*/
double getX();
double getY();
double distance(double, double, double, double);
double slope(double, double, double, double);

// begin main
int main()
{
    // declare variables
       double x1;
       double x2;
       double y1;
       double y2;

// read in variables for points on a graph
       x1 = getX();
       y1 = getY();
       x2 = getX();
       y2 = getY();

// print out the distance between the points and the slope of the line
      printf("\n");
      printf("Distance between the points is %.2f \n", distance(x1, x2, y1, y2));
      printf("Slope of the line is %.2f \n\n", slope(x1, x2, y1, y2));
}

/* begin getX function */
double getX()
{
    double x;
    printf( "Please enter the value of x:");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    return x;
}


/* begin getY function */
    double getY()
{
    double y;
    printf("Please enter the value of y:");
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    return y;
}

/* header for distance function */
    double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}


/* header for slope function */
    double slope(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you're in need of looking up what a struct or class is  (but your question isn't very clear)

Comment: I haven't been taught struct or class, I'm basically using the terms I've been taught. How can I make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "Struct" in C this will define new datatype that can sotre two or more separate values as below code 
-- please if you have any questions 
Code is Here :

/*Include statements*/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Given Prototypes*/
double getX();
double getY();
double distance(double, double, double, double);
double slope(double, double, double, double);

// begin main
int main()
{
    // declare variables
    double x1;
    double x2;
    double y1;
    double y2;

    // read in variables for points on a graph
    x1 = getX();
    y1 = getY();
    x2 = getX();
    y2 = getY();

    // print out the distance between the points and the slope of the line
    struct SlopDistance FinalValues;
    FinalValues = CalcuateValues(x1, y1, x2, y2);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Distance between the points is %.2f \n", FinalValues.Distance);
    printf("Slope of the line is %.2f \n\n", FinalValues.Distance);
}

/* begin getX function */
double getX()
{
    double x;
    printf("Please enter the value of x:");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    return x;
}


/* begin getY function */
double getY()
{
    double y;
    printf("Please enter the value of y:");
    scanf_s("%lf", &y);
    return y;
}

/* header for distance function */
double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
}


/* header for slope function */
double slope(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
}

struct SlopDistance
{

    double Slope;
    double Distance
};

struct SlopDistance CalcuateValues(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    struct SlopDistance FinalValue;
    FinalValue.Distance = distance(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    FinalValue.Slope = slope(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    return FinalValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the reply. The thing is I haven't really learnt struct and the IDE is telling me "Variable has incomplete type 'struct SlopDistance". Do you know how I can fix that? Do I have to define SlopDistance?

Comment: i tried this code on GCC stander compiler, BTW you can use pass two values to a function by reference or you can return a pointer to array of two that can hold the two values you need 
@mac_fan_33